# Squealing above 55mph

Tags: noise, dodge

I have an 07 dodge caliber it stared to make a whining, squealing noise at 55+ mph it's running and driving fine other than the noise what could cause that the belts look and feel fine

Comment: Wheel bearings? Alternator, belt tensioner, some bearing somewhere...

Comment: If it's alternator or belt tensioner you should hear the squealing noise at standstill when revving up the engine. In the worst case, it could be the transmission.